# How to copy and paste multiple datasheets whilst retaining the formatting of the destination (header & footer)

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a template document and then a document of datasheets. I need to be able to copy and paste these datasheets in bulk without the action affecting the header and footer positioning in my destination document (template doc). If I copy and paste each datasheet individually, it does not affect the formatting. However when i paste them all in bulk, it changes the positioning of the header and footer.

I've looked down every avenue on the internet and haven't found any solutions.

Anybody have any ideas on how to fix this?